# How to get the text from QTableWidget::setCellWidget()

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlabel

I'm trying to figure out how to get the QLabel text from `setCellWidget`.

I'm setting my `tableWidget` up like this:

```
    QLabel *nt = new QLabel();
    nt->setStyleSheet("QLabel {padding-left:1px;color: white!important;display: block;float: left;border-radius: 11px;font-weight: bold!important;border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #999999;background: #d675a7;background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,stop: 0 #f48282, stop: 1 #d00a0a);}");
    nt->setText("1");
    nt->setFixedWidth(22);
    nt->setFixedHeight(22);
    ui->tableWidget_3->setCellWidget(0,3,nt);
```

And I am trying to retrieve the value like so:

```
qDebug() << ui->tableWidget_3->item(0, 3)->text();
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: `ui->tableWidget_3->cellWidget(0, 3)->property("text").toString();` (updated)

Comment: Getting: `no member named 'cellWidget' in QTableWidgetItem`

Comment: See updated comment, please ^^^

Answer (score 1):

`ui->tableWidget_3->cellWidget(0, 3)->property("text").toString();`